# Is there a reference website/manual that documents the structure of the .iml, .iws and .ipr files from intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, configuration-files

As the title suggests, is there any documentation that describes what the content of the configuration files should be? anything from an xsd to a reference manual regarding it's structure would be helpful.

I am researching how to automate the setup of my idea workspace using gradle's idea plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some correspondence with JetBrains Staff, I discovered that the XSD files are not available for public viewing.

an excerpt from the email:

> "There is no complete references or XSD for these files. The format is internal and is not > designed for others to reuse."

If you want to generate projects, consider using Maven or Gradle, generate the files for these tools that IDEA will be able to import them.
Either that means JetBrains don't want you playing with their configuration files (I don't know how Gradle knows what to do) or the structure is subject to change and shouldn't be modified for backwards compatibility purposes (Say intellij updates their IDE and the config files are modified with a new structure, any programs designed to modify according to a previous structure may be invalid).